# Reshaping multiple sets of measurement columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr, reshape2, r-faq

I have a dataframe in a wide format, with repeated measurements taken within different date ranges. In my example there are three different periods, all with their corresponding values. E.g. the first measurement (`Value1`) was measured in the period from `DateRange1Start` to `DateRange1End`:

```
ID DateRange1Start DateRange1End Value1 DateRange2Start DateRange2End Value2 DateRange3Start DateRange3End Value3
1 1/1/90 3/1/90 4.4 4/5/91 6/7/91 6.2 5/5/95 6/6/96 3.3
```

I'm looking to reshape the data to a long format such that the DateRangeXStart and DateRangeXEnd columns are grouped,. Thus, what was 1 row in the original table becomes 3 rows in the new table:

```
ID DateRangeStart DateRangeEnd Value
1 1/1/90 3/1/90 4.4
1 4/5/91 6/7/91 6.2
1 5/5/95 6/6/96 3.3
```

I know there must be a way to do this with `reshape2`/`melt`/`recast`/`tidyr`, but I can't seem to figure it out how to map the multiple sets of measure variables into single sets of value columns in this particular way.

Comment: As a general practice, you might want to have a nicer naming pattern in the future. For example, it would be much easier/cleaner to work with "DateRangeStart1", "DateRangeEnd1", "Value1" (in other words, "VariableMeasurement") than having the measurement value stuck somewhere in a variable name.

Comment: Must the answer use `reshape2/melt/recast/tidyr`? (This question makes a better, more general dupe target if not)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Reshaping from wide to long format with multiple value/measure columns is possible with the function `pivot_longer()` of the *tidyr* package since version *1.0.0*.

This is superior to the previous tidyr strategy of `gather()` than `spread()` (see answer by @AndrewMacDonald), because the attributes are no longer dropped (dates remain dates and numerics remain numerics in the example below).

```r
library("tidyr")
library("magrittr")

a <- structure(list(ID = 1L, 
                    DateRange1Start = structure(7305, class = "Date"), 
                    DateRange1End = structure(7307, class = "Date"), 
                    Value1 = 4.4, 
                    DateRange2Start = structure(7793, class = "Date"),
                    DateRange2End = structure(7856, class = "Date"), 
                    Value2 = 6.2, 
                    DateRange3Start = structure(9255, class = "Date"), 
                    DateRange3End = structure(9653, class = "Date"), 
                    Value3 = 3.3),
               row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

`pivot_longer()` (counterpart: `pivot_wider()`) works similar to `gather()`.
However, it offers additional functionality such as multiple value columns.
With only one value column, all colnames of the wide data set would go into one long column with the name given in `names_to`.
For multiple value columns, `names_to` may receive multiple new names.

This is easiest if all column names follow a specific pattern like `Start_1`, `End_1`, `Start_2`, etc.
Therefore, I renamed the columns in the first step.

```r
(names(a) <- sub("(\\d)(\\w*)", "\\2_\\1", names(a)))
#>  [1] "ID"               "DateRangeStart_1" "DateRangeEnd_1"  
#>  [4] "Value_1"          "DateRangeStart_2" "DateRangeEnd_2"  
#>  [7] "Value_2"          "DateRangeStart_3" "DateRangeEnd_3"  
#> [10] "Value_3"

pivot_longer(a, 
             cols = -ID, 
             names_to = c(".value", "group"),
             # names_prefix = "DateRange",
             names_sep = "_")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      ID group DateRangeEnd DateRangeStart Value
#>   <int> <chr> <date>       <date>         <dbl>
#> 1     1 1     1990-01-03   1990-01-01       4.4
#> 2     1 2     1991-07-06   1991-05-04       6.2
#> 3     1 3     1996-06-06   1995-05-05       3.3
```

Alternatively, the reshape may be done using a *pivot spec* that offers finer control (see link below):

```r
spec <- a %>%
    build_longer_spec(cols = -ID) %>%
    dplyr::transmute(.name = .name,
                     group = readr::parse_number(name),
                     .value = stringr::str_extract(name, "Start|End|Value"))

pivot_longer(a, spec = spec)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

See also: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html

Comment: This is actually an answer to a slightly different question, namely how to avoid loss of attributes with tidy-methods.  The originally accepted answer (to use `stats::reshape`) never had that problem. And the original question clearly did not have Date-classed variables, either. The reshape function preserved factor levels and Date classes.

Comment: I totally agree that your `stats::reshape()` solution (+1) does the job equally well.

Comment: The regex can be simplified to `names(a) <- sub("(\\d)(\\w*)", "\\2_\\1", names(a))`

Answer (score 43):

```
reshape(dat, idvar="ID", direction="long", 
             varying=list(Start=c(2,5,8), End=c(3,6,9), Value=c(4,7,10)),
             v.names = c("DateRangeStart", "DateRangeEnd", "Value") )
#-------------
    ID time DateRangeStart DateRangeEnd Value
1.1  1    1          1/1/90        3/1/90    4.4
1.2  1    2          4/5/91        6/7/91    6.2
1.3  1    3          5/5/95        6/6/96    3.3
```

(Added the v.names per Josh's suggestion.)

Comment: +1 for showing off the power of that `varying=` argument. Following up, the `v.names` argument can also pretty up those column names, like this: `v.names = c("DateRangeStart", "DateRangeEnd", "Value")`

Answer (score 35):

`data.table`'s `melt` function can melt into multiple columns. Using that, we can simply do:

```
require(data.table)
melt(setDT(dat), id=1L,
     measure=patterns("Start$", "End$", "^Value"), 
     value.name=c("DateRangeStart", "DateRangeEnd", "Value"))

#    ID variable DateRangeStart DateRangeEnd Value
# 1:  1        1         1/1/90       3/1/90   4.4
# 2:  1        2         4/5/91       6/7/91   6.2
# 3:  1        3         5/5/95       6/6/96   3.3
```

---

Alternatively, you can also reference the three sets of measure columns by the column position:

```
melt(setDT(dat), id = 1L, 
     measure = list(c(2,5,8), c(3,6,9), c(4,7,10)), 
     value.name = c("DateRangeStart", "DateRangeEnd", "Value"))
```

Answer (score 20):

Here is an approach to the problem using `tidyr`.  This is an interesting use case for its function `extract_numeric()`, which I used to pull out the group from the column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a <- read.table(textConnection("
ID DateRange1Start DateRange1End Value1 DateRange2Start DateRange2End Value2 DateRange3Start DateRange3End Value3
1 1/1/90 3/1/90 4.4 4/5/91 6/7/91 6.2 5/5/95 6/6/96 3.3 
"),header=TRUE)

a %>%
  gather(variable,value,-ID) %>%
  mutate(group = extract_numeric(variable)) %>%
  mutate(variable =  gsub("\\d","",x = variable)) %>%
  spread(variable,value)

  ID group DateRangeEnd DateRangeStart Value
1  1     1       3/1/90         1/1/90   4.4
2  1     2       6/7/91         4/5/91   6.2
3  1     3       6/6/96         5/5/95   3.3
```

Answer (score 8):

Two additional options (with an example dataframe with more than one row to better show the working of the code):

**1) with base R:**

```
l <- lapply(split.default(d[-1], cumsum(grepl('Start$', names(d)[-1]))),
            setNames, c('DateRangeStart','DateRangeEnd','Value'))
data.frame(ID = d[,1], do.call(rbind, l), row.names = NULL)
```

which gives:

> ```
>   ID DateRangeStart DateRangeEnd Value
> 1  1         1/1/90       3/1/90   4.4
> 2  2         1/2/90       3/2/90   6.1
> 3  1         4/5/91       6/7/91   6.2
> 4  2         4/6/91       6/8/91   3.2
> 5  1         5/5/95       6/6/96   3.3
> 6  2         5/5/97       6/6/98   1.3
> ```

**2) with the `tidyverse`:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

split.default(d[-1], cumsum(grepl('Start$', names(d)[-1]))) %>%
  map_dfr(~set_names(., c('DateRangeStart','DateRangeEnd','Value'))) %>% 
  bind_cols(ID = rep(d$ID, nrow(.)/nrow(d)), .)
```

**3) with the `sjmisc`-package:**

```
library(sjmisc)
to_long(d, keys = 'group',
        values = c('DateRangeStart','DateRangeEnd','Value'), 
        c('DateRange1Start','DateRange2Start','DateRange3Start'),
        c('DateRange1End','DateRange2End','DateRange3End'),
        c('Value1','Value2','Value3'))[,-2]
```

---

If you also want a group/time column, you can adapt the approaches above to:

**1) with base R:**

```
l <- lapply(split.default(d[-1], cumsum(grepl('Start$', names(d)[-1]))),
            setNames, c('DateRangeStart','DateRangeEnd','Value'))
data.frame(ID = d[,1],
           group = rep(seq_along(l), each = nrow(d)),
           do.call(rbind, l), row.names = NULL)
```

which gives:

> ```
>   ID group DateRangeStart DateRangeEnd Value
> 1  1     1         1/1/90       3/1/90   4.4
> 2  2     1         1/2/90       3/2/90   6.1
> 3  1     2         4/5/91       6/7/91   6.2
> 4  2     2         4/6/91       6/8/91   3.2
> 5  1     3         5/5/95       6/6/96   3.3
> 6  2     3         5/5/97       6/6/98   1.3
> ```

**2) with the `tidyverse`:**

```
split.default(d[-1], cumsum(grepl('Start$', names(d)[-1]))) %>%
  map_dfr(~set_names(., c('DateRangeStart','DateRangeEnd','Value'))) %>% 
  bind_cols(ID = rep(d$ID, nrow(.)/nrow(d)),
            group = rep(1:(nrow(.)/nrow(d)), each = nrow(d)), .)
```

**3) with the `sjmisc`-package:**

```
library(sjmisc)
to_long(d, keys = 'group', recode.key = TRUE,
        values = c('DateRangeStart','DateRangeEnd','Value'), 
        c('DateRange1Start','DateRange2Start','DateRange3Start'),
        c('DateRange1End','DateRange2End','DateRange3End'),
        c('Value1','Value2','Value3'))
```

---

**Used data:**

```
d <- read.table(text = "ID DateRange1Start DateRange1End Value1 DateRange2Start DateRange2End Value2 DateRange3Start DateRange3End Value3
1 1/1/90 3/1/90 4.4 4/5/91 6/7/91 6.2 5/5/95 6/6/96 3.3
2 1/2/90 3/2/90 6.1 4/6/91 6/8/91 3.2 5/5/97 6/6/98 1.3", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using recycling:

```
data.frame(ID = d[, 1],
           DateRangeStart = unlist(d[, -1][, c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)]),
           DateRangeEnd  = unlist(d[, -1][, c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)]),
           Value =  unlist(d[, -1][, c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution in the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org/), which leverages the [`names_pattern`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html#arguments) argument to [`tidyr::pivot_longer()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html).

> `names_pattern` takes the same specification as [`extract()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/extract.html), a regular expression containing matching groups (`()`).

As a single command that requires no preliminary string manipulations, this might present an improvement over [@hplieninger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2563804)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55262457).

## Solution

```
library(tidyverse)


# ...
# Code to generate dataset 'ds'.
# ...


ds %>% pivot_longer(
  # Target only those columns names with a numeric index; possibly suffixed by "Start"
  # or "End".
  cols = matches("^(.*)(\\d+)(Start|End)?$"),
  # Break each name into its prefix, index, and suffix.
  names_pattern = "^(.*)(\\d+)(Start|End)?$",
  # Pivot by index and reassemble the other components.
  names_to = c(".value", "group_id", ".value")
)
```

You can further streamline the code into a one-liner, like so

```
pivot_longer(ds, !ID, names_pattern = "^(.*)(\\d+)(Start|End)?$", names_to = c(".value", NA, ".value"))
```

where `!ID` simply targets every column (but `ID`) as a grouped variable; and `NA` omits the group index (`group_id`) as in your example output.

## Result

Given a `ds` like your sample dataset

```
ds <- structure(
  list(
    ID = 1L,
    DateRange1Start = structure(7305, class = "Date"), 
    DateRange1End = structure(7307, class = "Date"),
    Value1 = 4.4, 
    DateRange2Start = structure(7793, class = "Date"),
    DateRange2End = structure(7856, class = "Date"), 
    Value2 = 6.2,
    DateRange3Start = structure(9255, class = "Date"), 
    DateRange3End = structure(9653, class = "Date"),
    Value3 = 3.3
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -1L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

this solution should yield the following result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     ID group_id DateRangeStart DateRangeEnd Value
  <int> <chr>    <date>         <date>       <dbl>
1     1 1        1990-01-01     1990-01-03     4.4
2     1 2        1991-05-04     1991-07-06     6.2
3     1 3        1995-05-05     1996-06-06     3.3
```

or alternatively for the streamlined command:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ID DateRangeStart DateRangeEnd Value
  <int> <date>         <date>       <dbl>
1     1 1990-01-01     1990-01-03     4.4
2     1 1991-05-04     1991-07-06     6.2
3     1 1995-05-05     1996-06-06     3.3
```

Comment: a simpler form : ``pivot_longer(a, cols = -ID, names_to = c('.value', '.value'), names_pattern = "(.+)\\d(.*)")``

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything fancy; base `R` functions will do.

```
a <- read.table(textConnection("
ID DateRange1Start DateRange1End Value1 DateRange2Start DateRange2End Value2 DateRange3Start DateRange3End Value3
1 1/1/90 3/1/90 4.4 4/5/91 6/7/91 6.2 5/5/95 6/6/96 3.3 
"),header=TRUE)
b1 <- a[,c(1:4)]; b2 <- a[,c(1,5:7)]; b3 <- a[,c(1,8:10)]
colnames(b1) <- colnames(b2) <- colnames(b3) <- c("ID","DateRangeStart","DateRangeEnd","Value")
b <- rbind(b1,b2,b3)
```