# Converting data from wide to long (using multiple columns)

Tags: r, transform, reshape

I currently have wide data which looks similar to this:

```
cid dyad f1 f2 op1 op2 ed1 ed2 junk 
1   2    0  0  2   4   5   7   0.876
1   5    0  1  2   4   4   3   0.765
```

etc

And I wish into a long data frame which looks similar to this:

```
cid dyad f op ed junk  id
1   2    0 2  5  0.876 1
1   2    0 4  7  0.876 2
1   5    0 2  4  0.765 1
1   5    1 4  3  0.765 2
```

I have tried using the gather() function as well as the reshape() function but cannot figure out how to create multiple columns instead of collapsing all of the columns into a long style

All help is appreciated

Comment: A hint would be `melt` from `data.table`

Comment: I _think_ this may be the canonical answer here: [Reshaping multiple sets of measurement columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns)

Comment: @akrun hwo do you use the melt() function in this instance?

Comment: @Henrik I don't seem to be able to replicate the code for my dataset

Comment: For getting what @Henrik suggested to work you may need to bind to two replicates of `junk` column to have the same size of variable columns in `reshape`.

Comment: `library(data.table); melt(as.data.table(dat), measure.vars = patterns("^f", "^op", "^ed"))`, to make the hint more explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the base `reshape()` function to (roughly) simultaneously melt over multiple sets of variables, by using the `varying` parameter and setting `direction` to `"long"`.

For example here, you are supplying a list of three "sets" (vectors) of variable names to the `varying` argument:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
cid dyad f1 f2 op1 op2 ed1 ed2 junk 
1   2    0  0  2   4   5   7   0.876
1   5    0  1  2   4   4   3   0.765
", header=TRUE)

reshape(dat, direction="long", 
        varying=list(c("f1","f2"), c("op1","op2"), c("ed1","ed2")), 
        v.names=c("f","op","ed"))
```

You'll end up with this:

```
    cid dyad  junk time f op ed id
1.1   1    2 0.876    1 0  2  5  1
2.1   1    5 0.765    1 0  2  4  2
1.2   1    2 0.876    2 0  4  7  1
2.2   1    5 0.765    2 1  4  3  2
```

Notice that two variables get created, in addition to the three sets getting collapsed: an `$id` variable -- which tracks the row number in the original table (`dat`), and a `$time` variable -- which corresponds to the order of the original variables that were collapsed. There are also now nested row numbers -- `1.1, 2.1, 1.2, 2.2`, which here are just the values of `$id` and `$time` at that row, respectively.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to track, hard to say whether `$id` or `$time` is what you want to use as the row identifier, but they're both there.

Might also be useful to play with the parameters `timevar` and `idvar` (you can set `timevar` to `NULL`, for example).

```
reshape(dat, direction="long", 
        varying=list(c("f1","f2"), c("op1","op2"), c("ed1","ed2")), 
        v.names=c("f","op","ed"), 
        timevar="id1", idvar="id2")
```

Answer (score 1):

The tidyr package can solve this problem using the function gather, separate and spread:

```
df<-read.table(header=TRUE, text="cid dyad f1 f2 op1 op2 ed1 ed2 junk 
1   2    0  0  2   4   5   7   0.876
               1   5    0  1  2   4   4   3   0.765")

library(tidyr)

print(df %>%gather( name, value, -c(cid, dyad, junk)) %>% 
  separate( name, into=c("name", "id"), sep= -2 ) %>%
  spread( key=c(name), value)
)


#step by step:
  #collect the columns f, op, ed to the common cid, dyad and junk
df<-gather(df, name, value, -c(cid, dyad, junk))
  #separate the number id from the names
df<-separate(df, name, into=c("name", "id"), sep= -2 )
  #made wide again.
df<-spread(df, key=c(name), value)
```