# 'varying' arguments must be the same length

Tags: r, reshape

I have longitudinal data in a wide format that I am trying to convert to long format:

```
#I have a wide data which look like this:
dat_wide <- read.table(text="
cid dyad f1 f2  op2 ed1 junk 
1   2    0  0   4   5   0.876
1   5    0  1   4   4   0.765
", header=TRUE)
#I want to convert it to long like this:
dat_long <- read.table(text="
cid dyad f op  ed junk  Visit
1   2    0 NA  5  0.876 1
1   2    0 4   NA 0.876 2
1   5    0 NA  4  0.765 1
1   5    1 4   NA 0.765 2 
", header=TRUE)

#R code I was trying:
dat_l2 = reshape(dat_wide,idvar='cid',  varying=list(c('f1','f2'), 'op2','ed1'),
                 #timevar='Visit',
                 times=c(1,2),
                 v.names=c('f','op','ed'),
                 direction='long') 
#gives error:Error in reshape(merge_wide1, idvar = "cid", varying = c("f1",  : length of 'v.names' does not evenly divide length of 'varying'
```

it's similar to [Converting data from wide to long (using multiple columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928328/converting-data-from-wide-to-long-using-multiple-columns)

The difference in my data is: I have some variables that were only recorded for fewer time points. eg.variable 'f' was recorded from both time 1 & time 2 but variable 'op' was recorded only for time2 (i.e. op2)& variable 'ed' was recorded only for time1 (i.e.ed1)
head(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` :

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(dat_wide, 
                    cols = f1:ed1, 
                    names_to = c('.value', 'Visit'), 
                    names_pattern = '(.*)(\\d+)')

#    cid  dyad  junk Visit     f    op    ed
#  <int> <int> <dbl> <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2 0.876 1         0    NA     5
#2     1     2 0.876 2         0     4    NA
#3     1     5 0.765 1         0    NA     4
#4     1     5 0.765 2         1     4    NA
```

Comment: This solves what I'hv asked here. Thank you Ronak! however, somehow it does not work for the bigger data I have. Gives error: "Error in `[.data.frame`(data, unique(names(data))) : 
  undefined columns selected" I know it would be difficult without looking at actual data but any solution?

Comment: @nnet The `names_pattern` is important here. You need to make sure that the column names follow the same pattern as shown in the example, if they are not we may need to change our regex.

Comment: Try to use `names_pattern` as `names_pattern = '(.*?)(\\d+)'`. Can you provide a reproducible example with your real data?

Comment: If you can share the names of the data that should give lot of clue. `dput(names(dataframe_name))`

Comment: I can see that you have `NA` as column name. Can you remove that column and then check if the answer works for you.

Comment: @Ronak your solutions always amaze me.  Can you please explain meaning of \\d+ here?

Comment: Thank you Anil. The `(\\d+)` part is to extract the number from the column names.