# How to Reshape data (with col name parsing)

Tags: r, reshape

need to reshape a data.frame from this

```
  TestID Machine1Measure Machine1Count Machine2Measure Machine2Count
1  10006              11            14              16            24
2  10007              23            27              32            35
```

To this:

```
  TestID Machine Measure Count
1  10006       1      11    14
2  10006       2      16    24
3  10007       1      23    27
4  10007       2      32    35
```

Below is code to create each. Looked at reshape in R but couldn't figure out how to split the names

Note: this is a subset of the columns - there are 70-140 machines. How can I make this simpler?

```
b <-data.frame(10006:10007, matrix(c(11,23,14,27,16,32,24,35),2,4)) 
colnames(b) <- c("TestID", "Machine1Measure", "Machine1Count", "Machine2Measure", "Machine2Count") 

a<-data.frame(matrix(c(10006,10006,10007,10007,1,2,1,2,11,16,23,32,14,24,27,35),4,4)) 
colnames(a) <- c("TestID", "Machine", "Measure", "Count") 

b
a
```

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/5977215

Comment: See also [Reshaping multiple sets of measurement columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns) and the 'Linked' posts therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.table` can do all this within one `melt`, which is almost 30x faster than the (perfectly working) tidyverse solution provided by MauritsEvers.

It uses `patterns` to define the columns with 'Measure' and 'Count' in their names, and then melts these columns to the columns names in `value.name`

```
library( data.table )
melt( setDT( b), 
      id.vars = c("TestID"), 
      measure.vars = patterns( ".*Measure", ".*Count"), 
      variable.name = "Machine", 
      value.name = c("Measure", "Count") )

#    TestID Machine Measure Count
# 1:  10006       1      11    14
# 2:  10007       1      23    27
# 3:  10006       2      16    24
# 4:  10007       2      32    35
```

### Benchmarking

```
# Unit: microseconds
#       expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
# data.table  182.265  200.3405  245.0403  234.0825  264.6605   3137.967  1000
# reshape    1757.575 1840.7240 2180.4957 1938.3335 2011.3895 100429.392  1000
# tidyverse  6173.203 6430.7830 6925.6034 6569.9670 6763.9810  29722.714  1000
```

Comment: Appreciate the use of data.table as that's what I prefer to use (over data.frame).

Comment: @eAndy yes, you can use regex in `patterns`, which makes it very flexible.

Answer (score 5):

The following reproduces your expected output:

```
df %>%
    gather(key, value, -TestID) %>%
    separate(key, into = c("tmp", "what"), sep = "(?<=\\d)") %>%
    separate(tmp, into = c("tmp", "Machine"), sep = "(?=\\d+)") %>%
    spread(what, value) %>%
    select(-tmp)
#  TestID Machine Count Measure
#1  10006       1    14      11
#2  10006       2    24      16
#3  10007       1    27      23
#4  10007       2    35      32
```

Explanation: We reshape data from wide to long, and use two `separate` calls to separate the various values and ids before reshaping again from long to wide. (We use a positive look-ahead and positive look-behind to separate the keys into the required fields.)

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "  TestID Machine1Measure Machine1Count Machine2Measure Machine2Count
1  10006              11            14              16            24
2  10007              23            27              32            35", header = T)
```

Answer (score 3):

And since nobody else likes `reshape()` any longer, I'll add an answer:

```
reshape(
  setNames(b, sub("^.+(\\d+)(.+)$", "\\2.\\1", names(b))),
  idvar="TestID", direction="long", varying=-1, timevar="Machine"
)

#        TestID Machine Measure Count
#10006.1  10006       1      11    14
#10007.1  10007       1      23    27
#10006.2  10006       2      16    24
#10007.2  10007       2      32    35
```

It'll never compete with `data.table` for pure speed, but brief testing  on 2M rows using:

```
bbig <- b[rep(1:2,each=1e6),]
bbig$TestID <- make.unique(as.character(bbig$TestID))

#data.table -  0.06 secs
#reshape    -  2.30 secs
#tidyverse  - 56.60 secs
```

Comment: @Wimpel - thanks - see my edit. The difference is more pronounced when you get bigger and bigger.