# How to gather columns in several steps in R without losing grouping

Tags: r, reshape

I need to convert a wide dataset to long and there are 16 columns which must converge to 4. Each 4 columns contain information related to one another and that information must not be "lost" in the transformation.

I have data from a ranking task of four block which has essentially given me a data set where the information is divided into four groups in a wide format. I.e first_image, first_sex, first_score, second_image, second_sex, second_score...

I have tried various combinations of group_by and gather() but I'm nowhere close.

I've already read [Reshaping multiple sets of measurement columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns) but I'm none the wiser I'm afraid.

I've made some sample data of what one participant's data looks like and I've also made a sample of how I would like the data to look.

```r
library(tidyverse)

sample_dat <- data.frame(subject_id = rep("sj1", 4),
                         first_pick = rep(1, 4),
                         first_image_pick = (c("a", "b", "c", "d")),
                         first_pick_neuro = rep("TD", 4),
                         first_pick_sex = rep("F", 4),
                         second_pick = rep(2, 4),
                         second_image_pick = (c("e", "f", "g", "h")),
                         second_pick_neuro = rep("TD", 4),
                         second_pick_sex = rep("M", 4),
                         third_pick = rep(3, 4),
                         third_image_pick = (c("i", "j", "k", "l")),
                         third_pick_neuro = rep("DS", 4),
                         third_pick_sex = rep("F", 4),
                         fourth_pick = rep(4, 4),
                         fourth_image_pick = (c("m", "n", "o", "p")),
                         fourth_pick_neuro = rep("DS", 4),
                         fourth_pick_sex = rep("M", 4))
```

Expected output:

```r
final_data <- data.frame(subject_id = rep("sj1", 16),
                         image = c("a", "b", "c", "d",
                                   "e", "f", "g", "h",
                                   "i", "j", "k", "l",
                                   "m", "n", "o", "p"),
                         rank = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), each = 4), # from the numbers in the first_pick, second_pick etc. 
                         neuro = rep(c("TD", "DS"), each = 8),
                         sex = rep(c("F", "M", "F", "M"), each = 4))
```

So far I've tried this, however it only duplicate all the information:

```r
sample_dat_long <- sample_dat %>%
  group_by(subject_id) %>%
  gather(Pick, Image,
         first_image_pick,
         second_image_pick,
         third_image_pick,
         fourth_image_pick)
```

So essentially I don't want to lose the information for each image (pick, sex, neuro) when I gather my data.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Do you need `final_data` as output

Comment: Not necessarily, as long as my data frame looks the way it supposed to.

Comment: So, the `final_data` is just to show the structure of expected output?

Comment: Yes precisely, I've updated the question.

Comment: How exactly do the columns in the first data frame correspond to those in the second? Where does the rank come from? You also might have better luck with `data.table::dcast` than with `tidyr::gather`, since it has the ability to reshape with multiple columns built in

Comment: My apologies, the rank comes from first_pick, second_pick, third_pick and fourth_pick.

Comment: try with `melt` `melt(setDT(sample_dat), measure = patterns("image", "neuro", "sex"), value.name = c("image", "neuro", "sex"))`

Comment: What package is that from?

Comment: It is from `data.table`.  BTW, what is the 'rank' column?

Comment: Well it's just a score whether a picture was picked first (1), second (2), third (3) or fourth (4) in a task. In the final_data table it comes from the first_pick, second_pick etc. in the sample table.

Comment: Can you check `melt(setDT(sample_dat), measure = patterns("image", "neuro", "sex"), value.name = c("image", "neuro", "sex"), variable.name = 'rank')[, .(subject_id, rank, image, neuro, sex)]` whether this s the expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `melt` from `data.table` which can take multiple `measure` `patterns` to reshape from 'wide' to 'long' format.  Here, the column names with substrings 'image', 'neuro', 'sex' are reshaped into separate columns to get the expected output

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(sample_dat), measure = patterns("image", "neuro", "sex"), 
   value.name = c("image", "neuro", "sex"), variable.name = 'rank')[, 
    .(subject_id, rank, image, neuro, sex)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do it column by column, as you want only 4 columns in the end.
Getting the indices of the column that should be put together in the first one (if i understood correctly):

```
  ind1 = seq(2,length(sample_dat[1,]), 4) 
  column1 = gather( sample_dat[,ind1] )[2]
```

And then repeat for all 3 other columns:

```
  ind2 = seq(3,length(sample_dat[1,]), 4) 
  column2 = gather( sample_dat[,ind2] )[2]
```

And you could even do this 4 columns with a for loop to not do it "manually".
And combine them back into a dataframe afterward

Comment: Hmm I tried this on the sample data and the subject is column is not there. I'm hesitant to use this method as I actually have 78 subjects and am worried that something's gonna go wrong when columns aren't grouped together.

Answer (score 1):

It would be worth to consider good column names (i.e. `"<variable_chr>.<time_num>"`). But we can fix it in a second.

```
pfx <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")

names(sample_dat)[-1] <- sapply(names(sample_dat)[-1], function(x) {
  x <- gsub("_pick", "", x)
  if (lengths(strsplit(x, "_")) == 2)
    sub("(^.*)_(.*)", paste("\\2", which(pfx == sub("(^.*)_.+", "\\1", x)), sep="."), x)
  else
    paste0("rank.", which(pfx == x))
})

names(sample_dat)  # good names now
# [1] "subject_id" "rank.1"     "image.1"    "neuro.1"    "sex.1"      "rank.2"    
# [7] "image.2"    "neuro.2"    "sex.2"      "rank.3"     "image.3"    "neuro.3"   
# [13] "sex.3"      "rank.4"     "image.4"    "neuro.4"    "sex.4"
```

Thereafter we may easily use `reshape`.

```
reshape(sample_dat, idvar="subject_id", varying=2:17, direction="long", 
        new.row.names=seq(ncol(sample_dat) - 1))
#    subject_id time rank image neuro sex
# 1         sj1    1    1     a    TD   F
# 2         sj1    1    1     b    TD   F
# 3         sj1    1    1     c    TD   F
# 4         sj1    1    1     d    TD   F
# 5         sj1    2    2     e    TD   M
# 6         sj1    2    2     f    TD   M
# 7         sj1    2    2     g    TD   M
# 8         sj1    2    2     h    TD   M
# 9         sj1    3    3     i    DS   F
# 10        sj1    3    3     j    DS   F
# 11        sj1    3    3     k    DS   F
# 12        sj1    3    3     l    DS   F
# 13        sj1    4    4     m    DS   M
# 14        sj1    4    4     n    DS   M
# 15        sj1    4    4     o    DS   M
# 16        sj1    4    4     p    DS   M
```

#### Data

```
sample_dat <- structure(list(subject_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "sj1", class = "factor"), 
    first_pick = c(1, 1, 1, 1), first_image_pick = structure(1:4, .Label = c("a", 
    "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), first_pick_neuro = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "TD", class = "factor"), first_pick_sex = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "F", class = "factor"), second_pick = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2), second_image_pick = structure(1:4, .Label = c("e", 
    "f", "g", "h"), class = "factor"), second_pick_neuro = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "TD", class = "factor"), second_pick_sex = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "M", class = "factor"), third_pick = c(3, 
    3, 3, 3), third_image_pick = structure(1:4, .Label = c("i", 
    "j", "k", "l"), class = "factor"), third_pick_neuro = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "DS", class = "factor"), third_pick_sex = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "F", class = "factor"), fourth_pick = c(4, 
    4, 4, 4), fourth_image_pick = structure(1:4, .Label = c("m", 
    "n", "o", "p"), class = "factor"), fourth_pick_neuro = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "DS", class = "factor"), fourth_pick_sex = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "M", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```