# How to stack multiple columns from household roster using tidyr

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have survey data where one respondent per household was asked about the age and education level of each member of the household. The data are wide, in the sense that there are indexed columns for the age and education of each household member.

Here's a simple example:

```
df <- 
  data.frame(
    HHID = 1:2,
    age_1 = c(4, 19),
    yrsedu_1 = c(8,12),    
    age_2 = c(7, 6),
    yrsedu_2 = c(14, 6)
  )
```

Thus `age_1` is the age of one member of household 1 and `edu_2` is their education level.

Essentially I want to stack the pairs of columns (2 columns per household member) to end up with a long dataset like this:

```
  data.frame(
    HHID = c(1,1,2,2),
    hh_child_number = c(1,2,1,2),
    age = c(4,7,19,6),    
    yrsedu = c(8,14,12,6))
```

How can I do this with `gather` in `tidyr`? The pairs of columns are causing trouble.

Comment: Is this question not covered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12466493/5325862) post, particularly the `pivot_longer` answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `gather` is retired you can use the new `pivot_longer` :

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -HHID, 
         names_to = c(".value", "hh_child_number"), 
         names_sep = "_") %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE)


# A tibble: 4 x 4
#   HHID hh_child_number   age yrsedu
#  <int>           <int> <int>  <int>
#1     1               1     4      8
#2     1               2     7     14
#3     2               1    19     12
#4     2               2     6      6
```

Comment: We seem to have gone full circle and `pivot_longer` isn't that different to the old  base R `reshape` - e.g.: `idv <- match("HHID", names(df));
reshape(df, idvar=idv, timevar="hh_child_number", sep="_", direction="long", varying=-idv)`

Comment: I wouldn't disagree, in `tidyverse` they keep on experimenting with a lot of things and finally agree that the good old solutions were better. :P

Answer (score 0):

It's not a `tidyverse` solution, but just to mention it, one alternative will be to use `melt` function from `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
age <- grep("age",colnames(df))
yr <- grep("yrsedu", colnames(df))

setDT(df)
melt(df, measure = list(age,yr), value.name = c("Age", "Yrsedu"), variable.name = "hh_child_number")

   HHID hh_child_number Age Yrsedu
1:    1               1   4      8
2:    2               1  19     12
3:    1               2   7     14
4:    2               2   6      6
```