# How to add labels for multiple lines in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df1:

```
 Year      V1        UR  CR         PA           FO  NA       TOTALLU
1   1850 7377211     0 0.03615170 0.1405466      0 0.8232772 0.9999755
2   1851 7377212     0 0.03622309 0.1397468      0 0.8240073 0.9999771
3   1852 7377213     0 0.03631065 0.1389448      0 0.8247278 0.9999833
4   1853 7377214     0 0.03639766 0.1381439      0 0.8254495 0.9999911
5   1854 7377215     0 0.03647239 0.1373441      0 0.8261718 0.9999883
6   1855 7377216     0 0.03655438 0.1365248      0 0.8269085 0.9999877
```

How can I plot 3 temporal lines of CR, PA and NA in one graph, and adding labels as well. I am doing this but my labels are only for two of the variables

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Year),ylim=c(0,1)) + 
geom_line(aes(y = CR), color = "red")+ 
geom_line(aes(y = PA, color="blue"))+
geom_line(aes(y = NA, color="green"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+ylab("LU")
```

Comment: You should reshape your data so you have one value column and another column with an indicator of CR, PR, or NA. Then pass that column to the color aestetic. Lots of resources on SO for that, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns)

Comment: May be you need `df1 %>% select(-V1, -TOTALLU, -UR, -FO) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Year) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value, col = name)) + geom_line()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach, with `directlabels` and `ggplot2`. Here the code where you have to reshape to long and then add the lines with `geom_line()`. As you want a label per each line you can use `geom_dl()`. Next the solution (I have selected only the variables you mentioned but you can modify that):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(directlabels)
#Code
df %>% select(c(1,4,5,7)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Year),y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_dl(aes(label = name), method = list(dl.trans(x = x + 0.2),
                                           "last.points", cex = 0.8,fontface='bold'))
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Year = 1850:1855, V1 = 7377211:7377216, UR = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CR = c(0.0361517, 0.03622309, 0.03631065, 
0.03639766, 0.03647239, 0.03655438), PA = c(0.1405466, 0.1397468, 
0.1389448, 0.1381439, 0.1373441, 0.1365248), FO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), NA. = c(0.8232772, 0.8240073, 0.8247278, 0.8254495, 
0.8261718, 0.8269085), TOTALLU = c(0.9999755, 0.9999771, 0.9999833, 
0.9999911, 0.9999883, 0.9999877)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)  

gfg_data <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                       y1 = c(1.1,2.4,3.5,4.1,5.9,6.7, 7.1,8.3,9.4,10.0), 
                       y2 = c(7,5,1,7,4,9,2,3,1,4), 
                       y3 = c(5,6,4,5,1,8,7,4,5,4), 
                       y4 = c(1,4,8,9,6,1,1,8,9,1), 
                       y5 = c(1,1,1,3,3,7,7,10,10,10))

data_long <- melt(gfg_data, id = "x")
gfg_plot <- ggplot(data_long, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable)) +  
  geom_line()

gfg_plot

# (source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a- plot-using-ggplot2-with-multiple-lines-in-r/)
```

Comment: You should explain why this answers the question. Upvote, btw.