# converting data wide format data frame to long format in data frame in r

Tags: r

I have a  wide format data frame abc.csv has variable ID, pc_2007-pc_2011 (value in these are postcode during different year) and rd_2007-rd_2011 (values in these are reveiw date for each year.

| ID | pc_2007 | pc_2008 | pc_2009 | pc_2010 | pc_2011 | rd_2007 | rd_2008 | rd_2009 | rd_2010 | rd_2011 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 | 7 | 10 | 13 | 16 | 19 | 22 | 25 | 28 |
| B | 2 | 5 | 8 | 11 | 14 | 17 | 20 | 23 | 26 | 29 |
| C | 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 | 15 | 18 | 21 | 24 | 27 | 30 |

i want to convert this dataframe into long format

| ID | year | pc | rd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2007 | 1 | 16 |
| A | 2008 | 4 | 19 |
| A | 2009 | 7 | 22 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping multiple sets of measurement columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `names_sep` in `pivot_longer`

```
df2 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df1, 
                    cols = -ID, 
                    names_to = c('.value', 'year'), 
                    names_sep = '_')

df2
#   ID    year     pc    rd
#   <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 A     2007      1    16
# 2 A     2008      4    19
# 3 A     2009      7    22
# 4 A     2010     10    25
# 5 A     2011     13    28
# 6 B     2007      2    17
# 7 B     2008      5    20
# 8 B     2009      8    23
# 9 B     2010     11    26
#10 B     2011     14    29
#11 C     2007      3    18
#12 C     2008      6    21
#13 C     2009      9    24
#14 C     2010     12    27
#15 C     2011     15    30
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see a suggestion below

```
    # your data
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), pc_2007 = 1:3, pc_2008 = 4:6, 
                     pc_2009 = 7:9, pc_2010 = 10:12, pc_2011 = 13:15, rd_2007 = 16:18, 
                     rd_2008 = 19:21, rd_2009 = 22:24, rd_2010 = 25:27, rd_2011 = 28:30), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                              -3L))
# packages needed
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

# suggestion
df %>% 
  # your columns names are difficult to work with, I propose you use a "transition" table and use 
  # regular expressions to select elements you need ...
  pivot_longer(cols = 2:last_col(), names_to = "year_code", values_to = "value") %>% 
  mutate(year = str_extract(year_code, "[0-9]{4}$"),
         code = str_extract(year_code, "^[a-z]{2}")) %>% 
  select(-year_code) %>% 
  # ...and then pivot your table back
  pivot_wider(names_from = code, values_from = value)
```

Output:

```
 ID    year     pc    rd
   <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
 1 A     2007      1    16
 2 A     2008      4    19
 3 A     2009      7    22
 4 A     2010     10    25
 5 A     2011     13    28
 6 B     2007      2    17
 7 B     2008      5    20
 8 B     2009      8    23
 9 B     2010     11    26
10 B     2011     14    29
11 C     2007      3    18
12 C     2008      6    21
13 C     2009      9    24
14 C     2010     12    27
15 C     2011     15    30
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `tidyverse` a way with `pivot_longer` followed by `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -ID,
    names_to = c("name", "year"),
    names_sep = "_"
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(ID, year),
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value
  )
## A tibble: 15 x 4
#   ID    year     pc    rd
#   <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 A     2007      1    16
# 2 A     2008      4    19
# 3 A     2009      7    22
# 4 A     2010     10    25
# 5 A     2011     13    28
# 6 B     2007      2    17
# 7 B     2008      5    20
# 8 B     2009      8    23
# 9 B     2010     11    26
#10 B     2011     14    29
#11 C     2007      3    18
#12 C     2008      6    21
#13 C     2009      9    24
#14 C     2010     12    27
#15 C     2011     15    30
```

---

### Data in `dput` format

```
df1 <- 
structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), pc_2007 = 1:3, pc_2008 = 4:6, 
    pc_2009 = 7:9, pc_2010 = 10:12, pc_2011 = 13:15, rd_2007 = 16:18, 
    rd_2008 = 19:21, rd_2009 = 22:24, rd_2010 = 25:27, rd_2011 = 28:30), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: thanks Rui for your  prompt response and code, really helpful. i do apologies for column names. what do you suggest for naming column name?

Comment: @saleem I don't understand, the column names come from the data itself, why are they wrong?

Comment: i made those variable names. i have data on postcode for 2007 to 2017 period, so i called pc_2007, pc_2008, pc_2009 and so on. similarly i have data on annual review date for same ids, so i called rd_2007,rd_2008,rd_2009 and so on

Comment: @saleem I believe that those names are good, they automatically become the column `year` in the long format.

Comment: @ Rui Barrads thanks