# Convert from wide to long format

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-science, tidyr

Hello how can I convert from wide format to long format with this sample spatial data with R

Sample Data:

```
origin  origin_x    origin_y destination      dest_x       dest_y       n
Paris   6587.54     44547.58    London     456474.5   8346585.4       1577
Milan   3949.45    5406644.6    Manchester 5437374.464  846347.99     8436
Toronto 86866.44    886254.4    Alberta   8327646.3   676442.98       2000
```

Expected output:

```
Key                X              Y                     n           
Paris          6587.54          44547.58               1577         
London         456474.5        8346585.4               1577         
Milan          3949.45         5406644.6               8436         
Manchester     5437374.46      846347.99               8436         
Toronto        86866.44        886254.4                2000         
Alberta        8327646.3       8327646.3               2000
```

[image: Image attached for further insight]

Comment: You can provide a useable dataset by copying the output of `dput(your_df)` into your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping multiple sets of measurement columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns)

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this works..I made a sample dataset from your image.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
sheet = read_csv('book.csv')
sheet

> sheet
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  origin  origin_x origin_y destination  dest_x   dest_y     n
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 Paris      6588.   44548. London      456474. 8346585.  1577
2 Milan      9386    23937  Manchester   39764  8239213   8436
3 Alberta     300      400  Toronto        200      100   2000
```

Separated it into origin and destination dfs..
Then merged it with rbindlist ..ordering it using the last column. This solution only works since n values are same a pair of origin-destination. If you had different n values..this will not work.

But this would only be one way of doing it. I think one can approach this in several ways.

```
origin = sheet %>% select(starts_with('origin'))
origin$n = sheet$n

destination = sheet %>% select(!starts_with('origin'))

x = rbindlist(list(origin, destination))[order(n)] %>% as.data.frame(.)
names(x) = c('Key', 'X', 'Y', 'n')

x

> x
         Key         X          Y    n
1      Paris   6587.54   44547.58 1577
2     London 456474.50 8346585.40 1577
3    Alberta    300.00     400.00 2000
4    Toronto    200.00     100.00 2000
5      Milan   9386.00   23937.00 8436
6 Manchester  39764.00 8239213.00 8436
```