Pivot / Transpose in R
Below is a sample dataset:
data.frame(
  Index = seq(1,5),
  X_50 = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE),
  X_90 = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE),
  Y_50 = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE),
  Y_90 = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE),
  Z_50 = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE),
  Z_90 = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE)
)




Index
X_50
X_90
Y_50
Y_90
Z_50
Z_90




1
3
5
1
10
3
4


2
8
8
6
6
9
7


3
9
3
3
7
7
4


4
3
10
8
10
6
1


5
7
2
3
5
10
8



I am trying to pivot the columns for the dataset to look like this:



Index
percentile_value
X
Y
Z




1
50
3
1
3


1
90
5
10
4


2
50
8
6
9


2
90
8
6
7


3
50
9
3
7


3
90
3
7
4



and so forth...
I tried pivot_longer, but I am not getting the above result. Can someone please help me out here. Thank you.

Does this answer your question? wide to long multiple columns issue and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns

You can use pivot_longer() function from the tidyr package.
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
        Index = seq(1,5),
        X_50 = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE),
        X_90 = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE),
        Y_50 = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE),
        Y_90 = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE),
        Z_50 = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE),
        Z_90 = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE)
)

df
#>   Index X_50 X_90 Y_50 Y_90 Z_50 Z_90
#> 1     1    2    1    3    5    2    5
#> 2     2    4    1    3    1    4    2
#> 3     3    2    5    5    4    5    2
#> 4     4    1    5    1    5    3    3
#> 5     5    1    2    1    2    1    1

df |> pivot_longer(cols = -Index, 
                   names_to = c(".value", "percentile_value"),
                   names_sep = "_") 
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>    Index percentile_value     X     Y     Z
#>    <int> <chr>            <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1 50                   2     3     2
#>  2     1 90                   1     5     5
#>  3     2 50                   4     3     4
#>  4     2 90                   1     1     2
#>  5     3 50                   2     5     5
#>  6     3 90                   5     4     2
#>  7     4 50                   1     1     3
#>  8     4 90                   5     5     3
#>  9     5 50                   1     1     1
#> 10     5 90                   2     2     1

Created on 2024-04-25 with reprex v2.1.0
